# In hibernate, what the entity-name property does?

Tags: java, hibernate

Does this means, we can use another name diff from it's class name in HQL?

such as:

```
 <class  name="package.UserEntity" entity-name="user" ...>
 ...
```

instead of use like this:

```
from UserEntity where userId=?
```

we can use HQL like this:

```
 from user where userId=?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per document the definition of name and entity name are :

`name`: the fully qualified Java class name of the persistent class or interface. If this attribute is missing, it is assumed that the mapping is for a non-POJO entity.

`entity-name` : Hibernate3 allows a class to be mapped multiple times, potentially to different tables.

Example :

```
<hibernate mapping>
    <class name="package.UserEntity" entiy-name="User1" table="User1">
        <id>.....</id>
            <property>....</property>
            <property>....</property>
     </class>

     <class name="package.UserEntity" entiy-name="User2" table="User2">
        <id>.....</id>
            <property>....</property>
            <property>....</property>
     </class>
</hibernate mapping>


Session s = SessionFactory.openSession();
List table1List = s.createQuery("FROM User1").list();

List table1List = s.createQuery("FROM User2").list();
```

Answer (score 1):

entity-name  is by default the class name.This name we can use in our HQL Queries like table name in normal SQL Queries.

You can give any entity name in mapping file and use it in your HQL instead of table name.

For example Table name is Users.Then u can give the entity name as User and use it in your HQL
like below

```
select userName from User
```